# linux - replace all double newlines with a space

Tags: linux, bash, sed, awk

Is it possible to replace only double newlines in a text file using sed, awk, grep, tr, or whatever is needed?

```
this

is

data
this

is

more

data
```

What I need to do is to replace all double newlines (\n\n, there is no whitespace) with a space, but keep all single newlines, as to have all my data points on their own line.

```
this is data
this is more data
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try

```
    sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n\n/ /g'  filename
```

This will first read the whole file, then replace the double newlines (and only those!) with a space. This trick (reading the whole file) is necessary because most GNU/Linux utilities process input one line at a time, which would give you the wrong result.

Comment: This command doesn't work for me. `sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n\n/ /g' file1.txt > file2.txt` results in both files having the exact same MD5 hash.

Answer (score 5):

Just another variant: an `awk` version

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS="\n\n" ; ORS=" ";}{ print }'
```

Comment: Note: `RS` is the intput record separator, by default a newline.`ORS` is the output record separator, by default a newline. As usual `man awk` to get more information.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to @MariusMatutiae's answer: If the file is too big to read to memory, you can use a classic but much slower way:

```
EMPTY=0
BUFFER=""
while read L; do
  if test -z "$L"; then
    EMPTY=$(($EMPTY+1))
    BUFFER="$BUFFER\n"
  else
    if test $EMPTY -lt 2; then
      echo -en "$BUFFER"
    else
      echo " "
    fi
    echo "$L"
    BUFFER=""
    EMPTY=0
  fi
done < filename
echo -ne "$BUFFER"
```